# Break vs Boolean?

Tags: python, boolean, break, continue, memory-efficient

My programming fundamentals teacher had said in one of her classes that using the "break" or "continue" keywords is less efficient then using a boolean to exit a loop.

I wrote and ran a program written in Python to see if this was the case:

```
import time;

TIMES = 100000000
COMPARE_FROM = "foo"
COMPARE_TO = "roo"

def breakTest() :
    while(True) :
        break;
        if(COMPARE_FROM == COMPARE_TO) :
            boo = "boo"

def booleanTest() :
    running = True;
    while(running) :
        running = False;
        if(running):
            if(COMPARE_FROM == COMPARE_TO) :
                boo = "boo"

def main() :
    breakTimeBefore = 0;
    breakTimeAfter = 0;
    booleanTimeBefore = 0;
    booleanTimeAfter = 0;

    print("running break test ...");

    breakTimeBefore = time.time();
    for i in range(0, TIMES, 1):
        breakTest();
    breakTimeAfter = time.time();

    print("break test complete");
    print("Time: %f seconds \n" % (breakTimeAfter - breakTimeBefore));

    print("running boolean test ...");

    booleanTimeBefore = time.time();
    for i in range(0, TIMES, 1):
        booleanTest();
    booleanTimeAfter = time.time();

    print("boolean test complete");
    print("Time: %f seconds \n" % (booleanTimeAfter - booleanTimeBefore))

    print("---- FINDINGS ----");
    print("breakTest time:   %f" % (breakTimeAfter - breakTimeBefore));
    print("booleanTest time: %f" % (booleanTimeAfter - booleanTimeBefore));
    print("diffrence:        %f" % ((breakTimeAfter - breakTimeBefore) - (booleanTimeAfter - booleanTimeBefore)));
    input("Press enter to close...");

main();
```

After running it three times, and averaging the results, i found that the breakTest was 6.25 seconds faster.

So is the break keyword more efficient or is my code wrong?

Comment: What's with the semicolons?

Comment: Ok, 6.25 seconds faster, but what were the total times?

Comment: oh... thats just out of habit.

Comment: Using a boolean won't let you take advantage of `else`, so TTHHHHHBBBBTTTTT! That is to say, this is a silly argument; do what needs doing.

Comment: Are you sure your teacher meant “efficient”, not “readable” or “clean”, which would at least be subjective? If your teacher really meant efficient, then s/he was wrong. There is no reason why one should fundamentally be more efficient that the other.

Comment: Note that you're only testing one loop iteration, so the actual difference in production code will likely be much smaller. But what @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams said - do what needs doing. If a bool test is appropriate, use it. If break is appropriate, use that instead. This is such a tiny microoptimization in the scheme of things that I'd be much more concerned with writing correctly, readable code than with any performance differences.

Comment: @Pascal, Thats what i thought, but i get docked marks for using the break keyword. QUOTE: "...no break statements, no global variables, non-redundant efficient code etc."

Comment: School isn't about learning the right thing, it's about regurgitating what you're taught. Do for the teacher what the teacher expects, and do for yourself the right thing.

Comment: I'll just point out in the examples that the `if COMPARE...` is never run, and `while True: break` is effectively your break test, but your other test has the overhead of binding a variable twice...

Comment: well typically school is demonstrating specific concepts ... eg learning how to sort, in which case using pythons `sort` method breaks the learning ...

Comment: Once you're at the point where you're being docked marks for break statements, you're long past first principles and deep into narcissism.

Comment: You can use %time ot %timeit to test speeds if you are using ipython...

Comment: It's not a particularly fair test, where the break one just breaks out, the boolean one then has to do the `if(running):` line which the break doesn't do.

Comment: @GP89 as I pointed out - along with the `running = False` and `running = True` :)

Comment: Might as well ask while i'm here... nesting "try..except"?

Comment: one: your code looks more like C than like python; two: loops, whose bodies are never executed don't prove much for comparison; three: the statement of the teacher is VERY debatable in a fundamentals course, since it depends not on the language, but on its implementation (which may easily change unnoticed). In either case the difference is more that of a little vs a big elephant than of a worm vs elephant. I would propose to use the most readable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tests are not exactly equivalent.  I think your teacher may have had something more like the following in mind:

```
def breakTest():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        if i == 10:
            break

def booleanTest():
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        i += 1
```

As you can see below, putting the condition into the while statement instead of having an if/break does improve performance (and shorten code):

```
In [14]: %timeit breakTest()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 999 ns per loop

In [15]: %timeit booleanTest()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 201 ns per loop
```

Note that this is just an example of the different ways to exit the loop and what I *think* your teacher meant.  Of course if you were actually writing this code, you should use `for i in range(11): ...`

Comment: But then I hope the teacher would point out in this case - don't use either, use `for n in range(10): # do something and possibly prematurely break` :)

Answer (score 2):

Intro computer programming courses usually teach you things like this as truisms instead of best practices, because it tends to be hard to convince people with little experience that best practices are worth the effort.  You should avoid using `break` and `continue` when you can, but they satisfy legitimate usecases that can't be managed, or in the least can't be managed cleanly, using other mechanisms.  For the things you do when first learning programming, leaning on things like `break` and `continue` tend to be lazy, messy solutions, so you should try to avoid them.  By the time you legitimately need them, you should have enough knowledge and experience behind you to use your own best judgement.

Comment: Wow. Your first sentence is itself a wonder truism. Spot on. I'd say you hit upon a Meta-Truism. :)